# VS Code as Git editor with --wait option doesn't let me edit interactive rebase file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I've setup VS Code as the global editor for Git on my Windows 10 pc like this:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

If I now run something like `git rebase HEAD~3 -i`, after *a long wait* VS Code is launched and I see that it opens a tab named `git-rebase-todo` but before I can do (or see) anything the tab is closed and the command line thinks the rebase is finished by showing something like

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/Maintenance.
```

I see this behavior when using both PowerShell and the regular Console.

This is the content of my global git config file:

```
[user]
    name = Wouter de Kort
    email = ...
[winUpdater]
    recentlySeenVersion = 2.15.1.windows.2
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

I thought that adding the `--wait` flag was all I had to do. Any idea why Code is opening and closing the rebase file in one go?